# ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2008, oracle10g

I'm facing

> ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

After hosting an ASP web page on IIS. When I test the web page with visual studio. The maximum open cursors exceeded problem does not happen.

1. What the cause of the problem happen & how can I solve it
2. When I close and displose the Oracle connection then will the opened cursors be automatically closed? If not, how can I close them?

Code I use to close & displose the connection

```vb
rdr.Close()
rdr.Dispose()
cmd.Connection.Close()
cmd.Connection.Dispose()
For Each para As OracleParameter In cmd.Parameters
    para.Dispose()
Next
cmd.Dispose()
con.Close()
con.Dispose()
```

Is my usage correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon you responses to the other answers, your problem is most likely the IIS web server is using a connection pool for your database connection. A connection pool will create a number of connections and, from the database perspective, keep them open for a long time. It does this because the assumption being made is opening a database connection is time consuming in relation to the duration of displaying a page.

You need to review the configuration of the IIS and either disable the connection pool (not recommended), or make the pool size smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I can't telly you if you use asp correctly or not as the code you posted is not complete. However the open_cursors init.ora parameter determines how many cursors can be opened by a database session at once. To determine if you are leaking cursors or if the parameter is set too low the first step is to determine the current value of the init.ora parameter open_cursors.

To determine which cursors are open (potentially forgotten to be closed). you can use the view v$open_cursor.

Comment: the database schema i using only allow 300 cursor, but each times i refresh the page..the cursor will increase 100+. but when i test the page with visual studio with same condition and parameters, the cursor only increase 10+ & the cursor will automatic remove in few seconds. but when the page run on server iis,the cursor increase too much & the time to clear the cursor become 10 seconds ++, any way to clean the open cursor??

Comment: I edited the answer, you can check with v$open_cursor what cursors have not been closed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's going here for sure without more code, but I can make a good guess:  **you're not closing your connections properly!**

Anywhere you see a manual call to .Close() or .Dispose() in regards to database connections, these calls **MUST** be located in a `finally` block (for preference, the implicit finally block created for a `using` statement). Otherwise, if any exceptions are thrown by your database code you might skip past the .Close() calls, thus leaving the connection hanging open and therefore vulnerable to things like your max open cursor problem.

It should look more like this:

```
using (var con = new OracleConnection(...))
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(" sql here ", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add( ... ).Value = ...

    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

I know I skipped past the some things in there (...), but that's the gist. I did not skip past any calls to .Close() or .Dispose(). The `using` blocks take care of that for us automatically.

Comment: Then you're lucky, because your short sample strongly suggests that you are doing this wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have a batch that do many request to bd with the same oracle connection. To resolve the problem, i close my ref_cursor after the rdr.read(). It's work for me. Just rdr.close()

Answer (score 0):

Dispose the OracleCommand:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Dispose();
```

However you also need to dispose and close the OracleDataReader:

```
OracleDataReader DataReader = Util.ExecuteDataForQuery(); // this returns the OracleDataReader object
// use it for your purpose
DataReader.Close();
DataReader.Dispose();
```