# ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded error

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I have the below code:

```
 using (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection dataConn = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand cmd = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = dataConn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Employees WHERE LOCATIONID=  :LOCATIONID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":LOCATIONID", locationId);
                    dataConn.Open();
                    retVal += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataConn.Close();
                }
                using (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand cmd = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = dataConn;
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE FROM Locations WHERE LocationId = :LOCATIONID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":LOCATIONID", locationId);
                    dataConn.Open();
                    retVal += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataConn.Close();
                }
            }
```

Just FYI,

- I am calling the above block in a loop of say 50 iterations.
- In each iteration, I am passing a new locationid.
  -The first query, for each iteration, is potentially deleting 500 records on    avg, as one location is assigned to 500 + employees.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150311/ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded-in-asp-net) link:, I think I am doing things correctly, can anyone please point why I am still getting the **ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded** error?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Ask your DBA to increase value of [OPEN_CURSORS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-FAFD1247-06E5-4E64-917F-AEBD4703CF40.htm#REFRN10137). I think the default value of 50 is rather low. Especially as it says: *there is no added overhead to setting this value higher than actually needed.*

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer in the link in your post ([ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150311/ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded-in-asp-net)), when you call dataConn.Close(), the connection is not really being closed, but is being left open in the connection pool. This is a hidden optimisation that makes it faster to open additional connections, but can cause problems with Oracle when you exceed some of it limits. I suggest you investigate ways of limited the size of the connection pool--this depends on what is hosting your code (IIS? Something else?).

You could also change your SQL to "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE key IS IN (...list of values...)". This will remove the need to open 50 logical connections (and who knows how many physical connections--potentially lots).

Or doing the looping within the dataConn.Open...dataConn.Close--just use the same open connection for all the cmds.

Edit: depending on which data provider you are using, the size of the connection pool may be controllable from within the connection string. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502(v=vs.110).aspx for an example.

Comment: I am using IIS, any lights on how I can investigate it there?